# Don't show an item in last value of loop

Tags: php

I have written a loop which prints a certain text with multiple OR conditions, however in the last item I would not like to print OR condition.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $vc; $x++) {

    echo "!empty("."$"."${"a".$x}) || ";

}
```

current output is

```
if(!empty($user_usertype) || !empty($user_drinking) || !empty($user_smoking) || )
```

I would like the output as

```
if(!empty($user_usertype) || !empty($user_drinking) || !empty($user_smoking))
```

i.e the OR condition should not be there in the last iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ternary operator or if statement:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $vc; $x++) {

    echo "!empty("."$"."${"a".$x})" . ($x == $vc ? "" : "|| ");

}
```

Is the same as:

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $vc; $x++) {

    echo "!empty("."$"."${"a".$x})";
    if($x != $vc)
        echo "|| ";

}
```

Comment: its telling me to wait for 8 minutes, i will certainly do that, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array, append the string at each loop, and then join it (`implode`), which is going to make what you want:

```
<?php

$arr = [];
$vc = 4;

for ($x=1; $x < $vc; $x++) {
    $arr[] = '!empty($user_usertype)';
}

echo 'if ('.implode(' || ', $arr).')';
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just change your loop condition to `$x < $vc` then after the loop add another echo statement for the last element? 
Saves checking a condition each iteration